# Getting error while commiting output from a private workflow to another public repo

Tags: git, github, github-actions

While trying to commit the output from a private workflow to another public repo I'm getting errors.

### My workflow output commit code

```
git config remote.origin.url 'https://<github_token>@github.com/<github_username>/<github_reponame>/'
git config --local user.email "<email_id>"
git config --local user.name "<username>"
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Updated"  
git push        
      - name: Push changes
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
 github_token: <github_token>
```

This is the error that gets on the GitHub action log.

```
remote: Permission to <github_username>/<github_reponame>.git denied to github-actions[bot].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<github_username>/<github_reponame>/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

**Can anyone help me to fix this?**

Comment: Do you mean push?

Comment: Are you sure you have permission to push to a public repo?

Comment: @LinFelix Yes push.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Do you mean about the GitHub token permission? If yes, it have.

Comment: No, I mean does your account on github have permission to push to that public repo?

Comment: @evolutionxbox That is my own public repo

Comment: Please may you check the github actions permissions for that repo? https://github.com/ad-m/github-push-action/issues/96#issuecomment-889984928

Comment: @evolutionxbox I checked, It has the permissions.

Comment: And yet, clearly it doesn't have permissions - what's not clear is where the disconnect occurs. However, `https:` URLs generally use `https://user:token@github.com/user/repo.git`, not `https://token@github.com/repo.git`, so that would be a likely place to start.

Comment: @torek Just now i tried. At last getting a error 'Error: Process completed with exit code 128.'

Comment: OK, so, different error now? The "exit code 128" is a generic Git failure.

Comment: @torek Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Need more info (why is it failing?).

Comment: @torek Don't know